# What is I on the vector space V over F.

Tags: linear-algebra

I personally think it's (1,1,1,1, ... ,n) so that all the elements is equal to 1, just want to confirm if I'm right!?

Comment: Unless $I$ has been defined as something, there is no reason it should be anything in particular. What properties should $I$ have?

Comment: What properties should you have? I is ( I am?) a vector space? Monty Python Math.

Comment: @DBF That sounds more like an Abbott and Costello routine.

Comment: @Tobias, right, but I is on first. Is you on second?

Comment: Similar to the identity matrix, but now only as a vector.

Comment: There is no analogue of the identity matrix for the vectors of some arbitrary vector space. The identity matrix is the one corresponding to the identity linear transformation. There is no analogue of this for the vectors.

Comment: Moreover, you need to give a basis to express a vector of a vector space as you do.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means the identity operator, since it is $\textit{on}$ a vector space. (ie it is not $\textit{in}$ so it isn't an element of $V$. So $I:V\rightarrow V$ is the function such that $I(v)=v$ for all $v\in V$.